# PHP - Convert "non" UTF-8 to UTF-8

Tags: php, utf-8, converters

In my XML file I have strings like:

```
"Schw&#xE4;bisch Hall Unicorns"
```

How do I convert this by using PHP into UTF-8 to get:

```
"Schwäbisch Hall Unicorns"
```

Update: Also, it would be nice to know how to do it vice-versa.

Comment: See [`html_entity_decode()`](https://php.net/html_entity_decode).

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you.
I just updated the question since this came into my mind a bit to late. Do you also know how I can do it vice-versa?

Comment: htmlentities returns me "Schw&auml;bisch Hall Unicorns" instead of "Schw&#xE4;bisch Hall Unicorns"